# Pyenv: no such command '--python' (Windows)

Tags: python, pycharm, pyenv

I'm trying to add a python interpreter with a pyenv environment in Pycharm.
But it gives me an error when it tries to execute the following command:

```
C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\pyenv-win\bin\pyenv.bat --python 
C:\Users\Laila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe install --dev
```

The error is `pyenv: no such command '--python'`

I have both python and pyenv directories on my PATH variable.
[image: Paths]

I can install a python version with pyenv just fine on the terminal.

What am I missing?

Edit: This is a screenshot of before the error.
[image]

Comment: Could you please attach a screenshot of the PyCharm UI you are using to create an environment before the error? Please also note `pipenv` != `pyenv`.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, thanks. As I expected you are confused by `pipenv` and `pyenv` names. They are completely different tools - the first one is used for creating virtual environments, the second one - to compile Python from sources. You are passing the path to `pyenv` where `pipenv` executable is expected.

Comment: ::facepalm.  You're right. Thank you for the clarification :/
I'll read about both thoroughly!